# Fabric website shows Unknown device after upgrading Crashlytics to 2.8.0 / 2.0.1

Tags: android, crashlytics

This is what we saw in the Crashlytics report page:

[image]

Interestingly, after I clicked "View all sessions", the device name sit right there:

[image]

I also found the device name in the downloaded crash log (via "Download .txt").

Apparently the device name was captured and uploaded.

But for some reason I can't find crash report by searching for device name.

We only see the problem after we upgraded Crashlytics & Crashlytics NDK to 2.8.0 / 2.0.1, the latest versions (from 2.6.8 / 1.1.6).

I am wondering if anybody else had similar experience?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for this report. I've raised it up to the team so we can get it fixed up. I'll update here once I know more.

Comment: This has been fixed now and will show the devices properly for new sessions that get reported.

Comment: Fantastic!
I have just verified it here!
Many thanks!

Comment: Awesome to hear it's fixed, Li!